# How can I create a Base Class for all my modules in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, class, module

I was thinking to create a generic base class and have each of the module base class inherit from it... but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say if you need a base class, you're not having real modules. I think modules should be "totally" independent sub-applications.

If you really want to write such a base class, use dependency injection, not inheritance so you can inject the needed common behaviour in all modules without creating such a tight coupling of all your modules. Just create a subfolder under 'application' and call it 'Base' or something. But again, I think it might not be such a good idea resp. if you need it, we're not talking about modules. Then again, each case is different.